# Dbuses and Apaches are using up memory

Tags: process, memory, memory-usage

I recently noticed, in System Monitor, that multiple Apache2 processes are showing up (with the same "Command Line"). There are currently 6 of them, each with 7MB memory. I also noticed a whole bunch of dbus processes. Is this normal, and is there a way to keep these from using up so much memory?
[image: Multiple processes (or threads?) with same memory]

Comment: Do you need the Apache processes? If not, it might be wise to uninstall Apache or to disable the automatic start.

Comment: Good point, I'm not always using Apache. How do you set it to not start on startup?

Comment: You can use the GUI program `bum` or there is something for the command line called `update-rc.d`, i.e. `sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove && sudo update-rc.d apache2 stop 20 2 3 4 5 .`

Answer (score 2):

The apache2 processes are probably threads of the main process, and the 7MB is shared across all those processes. Multiple dbus processes in the list are common, yes. They're not using as much memory as you think they are.

Comment: If so, why are the memory values different for same processes with same command-line values?

Comment: Your question said they were the same. Now you say they are different? Which one is it? Update your question with actual examples, perhaps.

Comment: Ok, see screenshot - many are same amount of memory, but not all.

Comment: Those are cups processes, and you have 2 different processes with multiple threads each, it would appear. And they are using less than 0.75 MB of RAM.